# How to get total count of specs (total and disabled) before test run when use sharding

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to get information about how many tests in total protractor is going to run/ignore before run?

As I'm using sharding spec reporters do not work well because they calculate tests within one spec file only.
Simple counting of `it`/ `xit` functions is not gonna work as I have many parametrized tests.

Comment: I would do something like this `cat protractor/functional_tests/**/*Spec.js  | grep -cE "^\s+xit"`

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not gonna work for me as amount of ‘it’ is much smaller than actual amount of tests